# shiny multiple objects in the same eventReactive

Tags: shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have a list of reactive objects that i defined with something like this:

```
myReactiveList <- reactive({

object1 <- some calculation depending on user inputs

object2 <- some calculation depending object 1 and on other user inputs

# put both in reactive list with:
list(
    reactiveObject1 <- reactive({object1}) 
    reactiveObject2 <- reactive({object2}) 
    )
})
```

Now i would like to add an action button so that the execution only happens once all user inputs have been selected and the user has pressed "Go".

Unfortunately the syntax `reactive(input$go , {})` doesn't seem to work.  It only works with `eventReactive(input$go , {})` which in turn can only work with one object at a time.

What would be the best approach to incorporate input$go in my sequential reactive list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap `object1` and `object2` in a list and call them later using `myReactiveList()[[1]]` and `myReactiveList()[[2]]` respectively -

```
myReactiveList <- eventReactive(input$go, {
  object1 <- some calculation depending on user inputs

  object2 <- some calculation depending object 1 and on other user inputs

  # put both in a list
  list(object1, object2)
})
```